# Why the TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am pulling data from woocommerce.

Which I have defined as so in my `render()`: 
`const product2 = this.state.products2;`

Now I want to target a particular value in this returned object as such:
`const defaultLace = product2.default_attributes[0].option`

However, the above renders a Type Error but `const defaultLace = product.default_attributes;` does not render an error and in the console I can see the data similar in this way;

```
      default_attributes: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Lace",
          option: "Closure"
        }
      ]
```

What is happening here that this `const defaultLace = product2.default_attributes[0].option` renders an error?

Any help?

---EDIT----

broken code replication: XXXX

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the error you are getting.

Comment: The codesandbox.io sample seems to work as expected - can you please give some more detail on the result you're expecting?

Comment: Thanks guys for your input - I've added the error replication above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`products2` is initially an empty array before the request has finished, so accessing `products2.default_attributes` will give `undefined`, and trying to access `[0]` on that will give rise to your error.

You could wait with the rendering until the `products2` array has been filled with data.

**Example**

```
render() {
  const product2 = this.state.products2;

  if (product2.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const productSize = product2[0].default_attributes[0].option;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{productSize}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Tholle that makes sense. Also why the reference to the index here `product2[0]` ?

Comment: @kadddeee It's hard to say without seeing how the request response looks like of course, but since you have an array in your state, I thought `products2` was an array after the request as well. You cannot access `default_attributes` on an array.

Comment: Hey @Tholle, does this work here? `const productSize = !!product2.length && product2.default_attributes[0].option;`

Comment: @devserkan If `product2` is an array, `product2.default_attributes` will give you `undefined`.

Comment: But if no length for this array then the left side will be false hence `productSize` will be false, nothing will be rendered. After fetch, it will be the needed value. Am not I right? I just try to think alternatives here, noting special :)

Comment: @devserkan Yes, but `product2` is still an array. Trying to access `default_attributes` on that will  give `undefined`, and reading `[0]` from that will give you an error.

Comment: Little bit confused here. `!!product2.length` returns false in the first time so we are not trying to access it. I think I need to try it. Thanks in anyway.

Comment: Yes `!!product2.length` returns a false. I've never seen this notation before so going to read up on it so thank you for bringing it up this potential alternative @devserkan. And thank you for taking time to explain @Tholle.

Answer (score 1):

This code is OK.

But when you retrive data from remote server you must check that data exist and are in your structure.

When you use

```
const defaultLace = product2.default_attributes[0].option
```

you must check data as:

```
if(product2 && product2.default_attributes && Array.isArray(product2.default_attributes) && product2.default_attributes.length > 0) {
    const defaultLace = product2.default_attributes[0].option
} else {
   throw new Error('Bad data');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Aleš Dostál